# call command from bash with argument variable with spaces

Tags: bash, macos

I have a bash script running on MacOS (Bash 3.2.57). The script takes arguments, and the arguments can have spaces. I would like to store the arguments in a variable and then call an executable. I can do this using eval:

```
arg="'file a' 'file b' '${1}'"
eval find ${arg}
```

And the result of `./test.sh` is:

```
file a
file b
file c
```

Are there any alternatives to using `eval` as I've read that I should avoid `eval`. When I try to replace with `exec`, I get the arguments split by space, when I set `IFS=''`, I get one long argument. I can't seem to find the optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks. That answer is very complete and provides exactly what I needed.